# Android Studio: Drawable Folder: How to put Images for Multiple dpi?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

Hi [as per android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) the drawable folder needs to have multiple sub-directories for images of different dpis. However in Android Studio creating any sub directory in the drawable folder causes it to fail to detect any images at all. On the other hand if an image is placed directly in the drawable folder it gets detected and becomes available for use view R.drawable.ImageName. In this case how do we use different dpi images for the same ImageName?

Comment: BY default stidio does not create any other  drawable folder..if you want you can create and place the images..

Comment: right click on drawable click Image Asset and select Notification or App icons just select your highest resolution image rest will be created automaticaly.. once you finish you can see different resolution inside drawable folder

Comment: New easy way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57330638/2527204

Comment: Now easy: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-birthday-card-app-image#1

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The standard procedures are:

1. Choose Project > app > scr > main
2. Right click "res", choose "New" and choose "Android resource directory"
   [image: Step 2]
3. In the opened dialog, at *Resource Type* choose **"drawable"**
   [image: Step 3]
4. In the list *Available qualifier* choose **Density**, then click the right arrow at the middle.
   [image: Step 4]
5. Choose the **Density** that you like then press **OK**
   [image: Step 5]

Comment: Even after doing this, I still cannot access the images!!

Comment: The method to add a folder is correct. I appreciate that. 
However to access the folder, you will have to change the Project Structure View from Android to Project. Here navigate to res->xxhdpi
@Fattie

Comment: @Fattie you can access by @drawable/your_file_name , it will automatically pick your file from drawable-xxxhdpi (in my case).

Comment: There is no `drawable` resource type to create drawable directory(atleast in latest version in windows)

Answer (score 26):

There are two ways of doing it.

1.Right click on drawable New->Image Asset->  select your highest resolution image rest will be created automatically. once you finish you can see different resolution inside drawable folder

2. The way you want. on the project Explorer window you see a dropdown as Android. Click it change to project.

Now yourprojectname->app->src->main->res->

Aila You can see your drawable folders with hdpi mdpi etc.

Comment: first way only adds icons

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way I have found to have the proper "directory" structure appear under the drawable folder for my icons is this:

1. Right click "Drawable"
2. Click on "New", then "Image Asset"
3. Change "Asset Type" to "Action Bar and Tab Icons"
4. For "Foreground" choose "ClipArt"
5. For "Clipart" click and "Choose" button and pick any icon
6. For "Resource Name" type in you icon file name

Now the pseudo-directories have been created for you under the Drawable folder in the Android view. Open up the true directories on your file system "main/res/drawable-xxhdpi", "main/res/drawable-xhdpi" and replace the icons in each folder with your own of the proper density.

Comment: Thanks, your way is easy and quickly.

Answer (score 14):

You don't create subfolders of the drawable folder but rather 'sibling' folders next to it under the `/res` folder for the different screen densities or screen sizes. 
The `/drawable` folder (without any dimension) is mostly used for drawables that don't relate to any screen sizes like `selector`s.

See this screenshot (use the name `drawable-hdpi` instead of `mipmap-hdpi`):

[image]

Comment: mipmap is only for icons for more check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders

Comment: Yes we need Sibling Folders not the folders below the drawable folders. This is the detail I missed in the documentation. Thanks for pointing out @Ascorbin

Comment: This is so utterly and completely confusing, I wish I was still doing it manually. In the android file explorer I have drawable-hdpi and all those folders but I can't access them even though they have images in them I never placed there. In my OS wm I don't have any of these, so I can't check the sizes and my app is slow so I doubt it's working properly. I'm just going to have to manually look up the pixel per dpi per folder and then scale everything and hope that fixes it instead of loading the broken hidden folders. Good thing programmers don't have anything better to do than resizing fml

Comment: @G_V You might be in the 'android' mode of displaying files in Android Studio. Set it to 'project' and you'll probably be happy :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458189/android-studio-layout-land-folder-not-appearing/29458229#29458229

Comment: I can see an image in hdpi and mdpi but when I preview all resolutions in the designer all I see is the hdpi image. How do I dell andriod "Display image I on resolution R"

Answer (score 11):

Simply go to **project Explorer** and  change your `View` from **Android to project** from drop Down and you are good to go.`There you can simply create folder like we do in Eclipse.` And in android project view it is hidden but when you switch to project. You can create folder like `drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

simply copy and paste the image into res>**drawable** and it ask you destination folder which you want to pate resolution image for more help please look for [Android Studio drawable folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784593/android-studio-drawable-folders/31047059#31047059)

Comment: This will work only if you have the folder already exists in drawable.

Answer (score 1):

In android studio you may see the following folder drawable xhdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi and more... 
You can put images of different dpi in these folder accordingly and android will take care which images should be draw according to the screen density of device.

**NOTE:** You have to put the images with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access image IDs using 
R.mipmap.yourImageName

Comment: This is the only answer that suggests how to access the images and it has been marked down. None of the answers here say how and image is chosen. It appears to happen by magic.

Answer (score 0):

New -> Batch Drawable Import -> Click on Add button -> Select image -> Select Target Resolution, Target Name, Format -> Ok

Answer (score 0):

Simply upload image to any online tool converter that will convert your image to different dpi(s) and then download and copy and paste from downloaded dpi folders to Android dpi folders.
For example, I have logo image to convert into different dpi(s), I searched in Google for online image converter into different dpi s, and then uploaded that imag and downloaded zip folder which contains different dpi folders, from which I copied one by one and pasted into same Android dpi folders.
That is done...