# How to manage drawable folder in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, resources, drawable

I just moved Eclipse Based Android Project to AndroidStudio.

And I figure out drawable folders got combined.

[image]

My question is...
How can I change image(xhdpi) to image(hdpi)
And How can I add more image and Make folder base image.png.(like this screenshot).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Drawable Folder: How to put Images for Multiple dpi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294287/android-studio-drawable-folder-how-to-put-images-for-multiple-dpi)

Comment: The image is not showing

Comment: This is already answered chheck here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33007226/5039767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change image folder (for example xhdpi to hdpi) is possible via right mouse click > refactor > move. And now you can select subfolder.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. the folders are separated still.
wow. Android Studio is Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see a `drawable` folder (xhdpi to hdpi) for the `DPI` that you need, you can create it yourself. There's nothing magical about it; it's just a folder which needs to have the correct name.

Curtsy [Yole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147024/yole) Sir