# Android Studio - layout-land folder not appearing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to support separate UIs for both portrait and landscape mode in my android studio project, for which I need to have a folder with name - 'layout-land', to create it I followed below steps:

1. Right Click on res folder and create a new directory

[image: Creating new layout-land dir]

2. Give name - 'layout-land'

[image: assigning layout-land name]

Problem is- the created folder is not appearing within res folder :(

[image: layout-land not visible]

I am clueless, please suggest.

Comment: changing to "Project Files" worked for me, but the folder layout-land didn't appear until I manually added some xml file there. (Manually I mean from windows explorer and not from android studio).
So I'm still confused, I guess there should be a better way

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That's the slightly confusing 'android' view of Android Studio. It shows only one layout folder (also shows only one drawable folder) which really contains all folders. Switch the view to 'project' and you'll see all folders.

[image]

Comment: Great. This is so annoying and freaked me out. I see this as a bug since you add the file in a different view and it does not change to that view.

Comment: but i cant do that then .. R.layout.layout2.fragment .. what can i do in this case ?

Answer (score 6):

I'm posting this just in case anyone really likes *Android* hirearchy of the project (note: other answers using classic hirearchy are correct as well).

All *layout* dirs with different qualifiers are categorized under name "layout". Just right click on the "layout" create your xml with any qualifier you need and you'll get this hirearchy (image below).

[image: All layout dirs categorized under "layout".]

Notice *activity_main.xml* is not a directorty but a category collecting all *activity_main.xml* files with different qualifiers.

This categorizing pattern appears quite often in *Android* hirearchy.

Comment: I'm having trouble with your solution. So, 1- I click new under layout 2- I do this ? http://i.imgur.com/OvQlAcS.png 3- ???