# Android Studio - Where is 'anim' folder?

Tags: android, animation, android-studio

[image]

The picture above is my default project structure of Android Studio.

I want to add my own animation xml file to anim folder and use it.
So I try to create a folder called 'anim' but it says that folder already exists
But I can not see ... how can I 'see' and 'access' anim folder?

Comment: Switch to the project view instead of android view

Comment: if its not there, create it. right click on res and you see an option to create directory

Comment: @Tasos I wrote at my question " it says that folder alreay exists"

Comment: ahh ok. something went wrong then. there's no way it will say the anim folder is there when you cant see it. did you create one before. should be just under res

Comment: plz add your android studio version

Answer (score 13):

I found!
After switching to the 'Project' view from 'Android' view,
explore to the /res folder and right click and create directory called 'anim'!

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Step 1 go to resource file and resource file

Answer (score 7):

Right click on res folder of your app. Then click on "New". Now select "Android resource file". Pop up will open. Select Resource type as: Animation, Name your file and click OK. Here you go...[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLQoE.png)[image: Step 2]

Answer (score 7):

## In Android Studio 4.0

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in Android Studio. Try to refresh state by changing view type.

Comment: is there any reference that its a bug??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458189/android-studio-layout-land-folder-not-appearing

Comment: Well, i experienced same with myself. I couldnt find any offical reference here you can another posts about it. https://teamtreehouse.com/community/problems-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Android Studio 3.4** and this is easy way follow these steps:

1. In Android Studio, right click on res folder
2. New > **Android Resource Directory**
3. Select **anim** for Resource Type
4. Done!

You can create your special ".xml" animation files.

Answer (score 0):

Anim is not default available in android project structure.

You need to create directory name it as anim.
res->new resource directoey.
Named it as anim.

Now for animation inside anim you can genrate xmls with respect of animation to use.

Refrence:

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/amp/

I used this refrence ,I hope useful for others also.

Anim is for animation purpose,you can use name as per your wish,anim is just file name,purpose matters not name.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry just right click on RES then click on Show Explorer and you will go in res folder in desktop create manually folder anim in res folder then you ll use it.easily

Answer (score 0):

If you not found anim directory file but you  created
 So, first you go in 
windows-> user-> click on private user name->
AndroidStudioProject ->your project name-> res -> search anim  file name and delete it..
Then you go to Android studio-> right click on res file ->new->Android Resource file-> write file name .xml->write anim name on directory name -> click ok
         Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. right click on res file
2. click on New the click on Android Resource Directory
3. then on Resource Type select anim
4. click Ok