# Using layout_weight for ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm using a RelativeLayout with an ImageView on the left. Here I hardcoded the layout_width for it with 150dp but this doesn't look good on other screens. On bigger screens the 150dp is fairly little. So I thought about using layout_weight but I can't use this on RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res    
/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/layout_quiz"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:padding="2dp"
    app:titleMarginStart="20dp"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base.TitleTextStyle"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_topic"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_question"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_topic"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_topic"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt_favorite"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Schritte der Trainingssteuerung. Was ist hier richtige Reihenfolge?"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/star"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/layout_question"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_topic"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_topic"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"  
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_multiplechoice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_question"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_multiplechoice_solutions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_solution1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_solution2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_solution3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_solution4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_solution5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_multiplechoice_answers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_singlechoice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_question"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_singlechoice_solutions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg_solution_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_solution1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_solution2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_solution3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_solution4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_solution5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_singlechoice_answers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg_answer_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_answer1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_answer2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_answer3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_answer4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_answer5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout_progressbar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_question"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_infotitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/sv_infoscroller"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_infotext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_infotitle"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_infopicture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_infotext"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/layout_progressbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_progressbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/view"   
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view" android:gravity="bottom"  
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
        android:text="@string/next"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt_next"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bt_next"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_resultmessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left"
        android:text="@string/back"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_quiz"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bt_back"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:progress="1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" android:src="@drawable/schmuck"/>
```

[image]

Do you know a solution for this?

Comment: would you share your xml code?

Answer (score 4):

you can use `PercentRelativeLayout`

```
     <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Add this to your gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
```

see the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

Comment: Don't you think that image may pixelate?

Comment: @AnuragSingh yes image can pixelate if it is very small in large screens...you can use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` for imageview ...so the image holds it's dimension..but it is better approach to put different size of images in `drawable` folders http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294287/android-studio-drawable-folder-how-to-put-images-for-multiple-dpi

Comment: In my opinion even putting images in different drawable will still pixelate. PercentLayout will be of more help in ViewGroup where we want to use the unused space instead of using weights.

Comment: what do you say to above?

Comment: If u know a better approach feel free to share!..percent layout used in many cases other than what u said..

Answer (score 0):

You should define a dimension in two dimens.xml based on screen size. Then to the same dimension res you can assign a different value in dp.

To do so you can create some folder like

```
values-hdpi
values-large
values-sw600dp
```

depending on what you need and put these dimens.xml files into these folders.

Answer (score 0):

Since `PercentRelativeLayout` is a good option as @rafsanahmad007 said, but still if you want to use the same layout with weight_sum, you need a small modification, something like this

```
<LinearLayout
 android_orientation:vertical> //parent layout

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

  //this will have two further layout, left include image and text, right for other views and total weightSum for both
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:weightSum="your_desired_weight_sum">

      <LayoutLeft>
      add any layout with layout weight 
      </LayoutLeft> 

      <LayoutRight>
      add any layout with layout weight 
      </LayoutRight> 
   <LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Since it is rough view hierarchy to give you whole idea, forgive me if couldn't get :)