# I only got one mipmap directory. (xhdpi,mdpi,xxhdpi etc are missing)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-mipmap

When i implement an ImageView the quality is very low and i cant choose between mipmap folders (xhdpi,mhdpi,xxhdpi etc.). The images are all in one directoy so i cant define in with src or background.

[Here a picture of my res directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpPN3.png)

How can i achieve an imageview with a good resolution.? I tried several ways and it not seem to work out. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

mipmap folders are only used for the launcher icons. You have to use the drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi etc for the different size images.

Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294287/android-studio-drawable-folder-how-to-put-images-for-multiple-dpi).

You can see only directory for mipmap but all the ic_launcher images are there.

Comment: Thanks i got the directories now. But when i want to make a new Image Asset it gets automatically saved in mipmap. why is this the case?

Comment: Have you created drwable-hdpi and other folders in res folder?

Comment: i now inserted the image manually in the drawable folder and it works. why it doesnt when i do it with new->image asset->launcher icons.

Comment: Because you are selecting the launcher icons and the launcher icons are always go into mipmap folder.

Comment: and how i insert a image "normally"? edit: google is my friend :P . ty Chirag for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Where you can download your assets as zip file which you can extract to different directories like xhdpi,mdpi,xxhdpi. Then you can copy that it to the resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

you should add xhdpi,mdpi,xxhdpi as directories in the res folder
right click res>> new >>Android resource directory
select resource type as mipmap and 
available qualifiers select density then click the >> button 
select on of the densities from the drop down menu 
repeat for each density you need.

then place each designated image in its own density folder, android should then automatically use the resource that matches every screen density